# UILabel text property iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I would like to modify the text property of a UILabel (nameLbl) but don't know what i am wrong.

I have 2 Views, the first is a ViewController, the second is ProfileViewController. The ProfileViewController fill some field of user profile this data are passed to ViewController and showed in UIlabel.

The issue is I can't show the datas in the ViewController.

What am I get wrong?

```
---ViewController.h---
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{
    IBOutlet ViewController *profile;

    IBOutlet UILabel *nameLbl, *celLbl, *cfLbl;

    IBOutlet UITextField *nameTF;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ViewController *profile;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLbl, *celLbl, *cfLbl;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTF;

-(void) setUser: (NSString *) name:(NSString *) cel:(NSString *) cf;

@end

---ViewController.m---

@synthesize nameLbl, celLbl, cfLbl;

-(void) setUser:(NSString *)name:(NSString *)cel:(NSString *)cf
{
    nameLbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    [nameLbl setText:name];
}
```

this is the connection inspector

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz7WcQmZNuFLMWt3QUo1Tk5XUW8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `The issue is I can't show the datas in the ViewController.`. What happens when you try?

Comment: it don't modify the label text, but neither got error message

Comment: Side note - please find a better tutorial. The one you are following is out of date. You should not be adding ivars for your properties and you should not be calling `@synthesize`. That used to be needed a few years ago but not any more.

Comment: @rmaddy do you have a tutorial o something else to suggest to me (a site, a youtube channel..)?

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
nameLbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

from your code it seems that the `nameLbl` `UILabel` has already been initialized from nib, and you are creating a new memory reference, so its not working.

Comment: i tried but doesn't seem going, no error, no change label text

Comment: @ilgatto85 I guess then your IBOutlet is not connected to UILabel in your xib, please check.

Comment: i checked, rewired the IBOutlet but nothing changes

Comment: @ilgatto85, do you ever call your method, setUser:name:cel:?

Comment: yes, I call the method and it pass the parameters correctly, the issue is in the refresh of the text's label